# How to have fixed options using Option.Applicative in haskell?

Tags: parsing, haskell, optparse-applicative

Lets say I am building an interface with the following command:

```bash
$ run --display (file/env/db) # default to file if invalid is entered
```

What I am looking for specifically is how to obtain an enum value with the following:

Given:

```
data type = File | Env | Db
```

When the command `run --display file` is entered, the enum `File` is returned.

As far as I know, the `strOption` and `strArgument` functions are used for any arbitrary string argument. I have read the complete documentation but couldn't figure out any easy solution for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can work with a custom reader: https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative#option-readers

Answer (score 1):

You can work with a custom parser, like:

```
import Data.Char(toLower)
import Options.Applicative(ReadM, eitherReader)

data OutputType = File | Env | Db

parseOutputType :: ReadM OutputType
parseOutputType = eitherReader $ (go . map toLower)
  where go "file" = Right File
        go "env" = Right Env
        go "db" = Right Db
        go _ = Left "Enter a valid option: file, env, or db"
```

and then parse the options with:

```
import Options.Applicative

data MyOptions = MyOptions { display :: OutputType }

parseOptions :: Parser MyOptions
parseOptions = MyOptions <$> option parseOutputType (long "display")
```